# simple mysql query count fails

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
SELECT          
    count(t1.id) AS c1
FROM
    table2
    LEFT JOIN table1 AS t1 ON (t1.uid = table2.uid)
WHERE
    table2.mode = 'ls'
GROUP BY
    t1.id
```

c1 = 6 -> CORRECT!

```
SELECT          
    count(t2.id) AS c2
FROM
    table2
    LEFT JOIN table1 AS t2 ON (t2.pid = table2.id)
WHERE
    table2.mode = 'ls'
GROUP BY
    t1.id
```

c2 = 1 -> CORRECT!

```
SELECT          
    count(t1.id) AS c1,
    count(t2.id) AS c2
FROM
    table2
    LEFT JOIN table1 AS t1 ON (t1.uid = table2.uid)
    LEFT JOIN table1 AS t2 ON (t2.pid = table2.id)
WHERE
    table2.mode = 'ls'
GROUP BY
    t1.id
```

c1 = 6 -> CORRECT!

**c2 = 6 -> WRONG!**

**How do I request both counts in one query, without getting wrong results?**

I need to count two different requests at the same table (table1).

so, I'm using an alias for both request. (t1). Each alias-request is working fine alone. If I use both in the same query, i got wrong results.

Comment: Please include the data you are using, the results you expect and the full query.  If you feel it appropriate to strip certain parts away, do so to the entire problem; but still supply full results and full queries, but just for the simplified problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count()` will get you the number of records that are returned by your query. Since if you removed the counts and replaced it with `*` you would have 6 rows both of those counts are giving you 6.

Is there any reason why you cant use two sub selects and return the result of each of those?

So:

```
SELECT subQ1.c1, subQ2.c2 FROM
    (SELECT count(t1.id) AS c1 FROM table2
        LEFT JOIN table1 AS t1 ON (t1.uid = table2.uid)
        WHERE table2.mode = 'ls') as subQ1, 
    (SELECT count(t2.id) AS c2 FROM table2
        LEFT JOIN table1 AS t2 ON (t2.pid = table2.id)
        WHERE table2.mode = 'ls') as SubQ2;
```

Comment: Thanks. That works fine.

count(t1.id) AS c1,
(SELECT count(table1 .id) FROM table1 WHERE table1.pid=table12.id) AS c2

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem on the full query is your group by function. You are grouping by t.id, thus a1.id will have a different count based on how many rows you have.

What I mean by this is if there are 6 rows in table t, then count is going to return 6 for table t; but also since there looks to be a 1 to 1 relation on table a, there are 6 matching rows in table a to the 6 matching rows in table t. such that

t.id = a.id
1 = 1
2= 2 ...etc.

Thus your count is returning rows versus the count you believe you should have? I believe sum function is what you want to use here.

Comment: same problem without GROUP BY clause, which is not necessary anymore. If GROUP would be the problem, is should not work when i took one count out. but it does!

Comment: Without sample data i was taking a small shot in the dark. How about the sum function? Did you try that?

Comment: I'm sorry. You're probably right. I was overworked yesterday. The wrong results are based on the GROUP BY clause. Unfortunately the SUM solution has been deleted by user. I did not found a new SUM-solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this...but I'm not really sure what you're trying to do.

```
SELECT (...)
    count(CASE WHEN t1.uid = t3.uid THEN t1.id ELSE NULL END) AS CBanz,
    count(CASE WHEN ta1.pid = t3.id THEN a1.id ELSE NULL END) AS CBanz1
FROM
    t0
    LEFT JOIN (...)
    LEFT JOIN t1 ON (t1.uid = t3.uid)
    LEFT JOIN t1 AS a1 ON (a1.pid = t3.id)
WHERE (...)
```